# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host with ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a bastion host where I have configured the `~/.ssh/config` file as follows:

```
Host stage-bastion
        ProxyCommand   ssh -q stage-bastion nc -q0 <capped-ip> 22
        Hostname       <capped-ip>
        User stage
        IdentityFile /home/abc/Documents/key
        Port 1984
        ServerAliveInterval     15
        ServerAliveCountMax     3
```

And I try to log in as follows:

```
ssh stage-bastion
```

and I get the error:

> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

I even did a `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` but not luck.

Then I tried normally as below:

```
ssh -i /home/abc/Documents/key stage@<capped-ip>
```

Voila it worked and I was able to `ssh`.

Can someone help me why my `~/.ssh/config` is not working and giving the above error?